# Combining for loop with setInterval()

Tags: javascript, for-loop, setinterval

My objective is to log each of the coordinate pairs to the console in the `coords` variable in succession every 5 seconds.  I am able to do this with every pair in `coords` all at once with the `setInterval()` function, but how would I log `coords[0]` at 5 seconds, `coords[1]` at 10 seconds, `coords[2`] at 15 seconds, and so on - and then start over when finished?

```
coords = [[ -122.68181, 45.523713333333333 ], [ -122.681848333333363, 45.52369833333335 ], 
[ -122.681996666666691, 45.523683333333338 ], [ -122.682078333333351, 45.523733333333332 ],
[ -122.681916666666694, 45.523736666666665 ], [ -122.6815766666667, 45.523753333333346 ], 
[ -122.68182333333M3355, 45.523741666666659 ], [ -122.681823333333355, 45.523753333333339 ],
[ -122.681656666666683, 45.52375 ], [ -122.68162833333335, 45.523738333333334 ], [ -122.681936666666701, 45.52373 ]]

function listCoords() {
  for (var i=0, l=coords.length; i<l; i++) { 
    console.log(coords[i])
  }
}

setInterval(function(){
 listCoords()
}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var i=0;
function listCoords() { 
   console.log(coords[i])
   i=(i+1)%coords.length;
}

setInterval(listCoords,5000);
```

Simply keep a global variable which stores the position to show next. If the function gets called, show this value, increase i and prevent that it jumps outside of the arrays bounds. This works like this:

imagine an array length of 3, itll do

```
0
(0+1)%3 = 1
(1+1)%3 = 2
(2+1)%3 = 0 // the loop starts again
```

Alternatively use some pseudo recursion and timeouts:

```
;/*a semicolon, just for Andy ;) */
(function next(i){
   console.log(coords[i]);
   setTimeout(next,5000,(i+1)%coords.length);// show next one in 5 secs
})(0);//start with 0
```

Comment: how can one understand `i=++%coords.length;`?

Answer (score 0):

Embed a `setTimeout` within the function, that calls the function only if the index is less than the length of `coords` Here we use an immediately-invoked function expression (IIFE) to pass in `coords` and an initial value of i.

```
var listCoords = (function listCoords(coords, i) {
  if (i && i <= coords.length) console.log(coords[i - 1]);
  setTimeout(listCoords, 5000, coords, ++i)
}(coords, 0));
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/kf80wyqb/12/) - the demo operates at 1 second rather than 5.

Comment: What should global listCoords contain? (Its probably undefined) and how does that differ from my answer?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. You'll probably want to amend your code to add a semi-colon in front of the opening parenthesis in that case.